# Long Link RMQ clustering

Tags: rabbitmq, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, activemq-artemis

Sorry for what may seem a simple question to some, but we currently use RMQ for pretty simple client/Queue/Consumer type transactions.  Some use return message queues, while others are just simple 'jobs'.
Looking to distribute between 'sites' and for use-cases of RMQ-Clustering with nodes that are not co-located, ie: on WAN.

Has anyone done such a thing, or should I bite-the-bullet and move to ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: Asking whether or not anybody has "done such a thing" can be answered either "yes" or "no." It's not specific enough to be meaningful. Also, there are way too many factors for anybody on Stack Overflow to tell you whether or not you _should_ move to a completely different message broker. Stack Overflow is really for clear, specific programming questions to which the community can provide fact-based answers. The questions you've asked here are off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ 5's network connectors are designed to support the "long link" or WAN connectivity pattern (along with others). The messaging pattern is known as 'store-and-forward'. It supports one-way push, bi-directional and pull approaches.

Network of Brokers
ref: https://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers